# Dygraphs not working with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, dygraphs

I'm new to AngularJS and building a dashboard with [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/).

Tried to put the [example code](http://dygraphs.com/data.html) from the dygraphs website  in an ng-repeat-list, just to test. Expected the same sample graph for every x in y. Unfortunately the graph doesn't get drawn, just the axes, console doesn't show any errors.

```
<li ng-repeat="x in y">
    <div id="graph">
        <script>
            new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
                   [ [1,10,100], [2,20,80], [3,50,60], [4,70,80] ],
                   { labels: [ "x", "A", "B" ] });
        </script>
    </div>
</li>
```

If I remove ng-repeat, it works though (single graph) – so the dygraphs-code is valid. Of course it doesn't make sense to draw the graphs directly in the view like I did here, still I wonder why it doesn't work. Am I missing some general point here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is that Angular will repeat your `<div id="graph">` n times. So you now have n times div with id of 'graph' which are siblings. Therefore, when you call `document.getElementById('graph')`, that won't work very well.

That said, I don't know how well script tags inside ng-repeat works either, seems like a very strange use case.

The proper way to do this (as with all DOM related operations), is to use a directive. Here's an example:

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.graphs = [
        {
            data: [ [1,10,100], [2,20,80], [3,50,60], [4,70,80] ],
            opts: { labels: [ "x", "A", "B" ] }

        },
        {
            data: [ [1,10,200], [2,20,42], [3,50,10], [4,70,30] ],
            opts: { labels: [ "label1", "C", "D" ] }

        }
    ];
});

myApp.directive('graph', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', // Use as element
        scope: { // Isolate scope
            data: '=', // Two-way bind data to local scope
            opts: '=?' // '?' means optional
        },
        template: "<div></div>", // We need a div to attach graph to
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            var graph = new Dygraph(elem.children()[0], scope.data, scope.opts );
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <graph ng-repeat="graph in graphs" data="graph.data" opts="graph.opts"></graph>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hWQ6/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that made directives a lot clearer to me and did the job!

Comment: Nice answer, I've found a small problem while working with this is that I can not see to find a way to specify a div to be used for the labels. Any idea on how to add it? Since the labelsDiv need to be specified in the data using a ID I can not find my way around it :(

Comment: I assume you're referring to the `labelsDiv`. According to the docs, you can also pass in an element. So you add a new div in which you want the labels to appear in into the template of the directive. So you'll have two sibling divs, one for the graph itself and one for the labels. Then you fetch out both elements, and inject the label element's reference into the data you provide to dygraph, and the graph element you provide to dygraph constructor as before. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: @SveinT . thanks sharing for your answer. My question related to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521905/set-one-showrangeselector-for-two-dygraph