# Ng-repeat doesn't use options from directive

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-ng-repeat, dygraphs

I was able to use [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com) in ng-repeat after directives have been made clearer to me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468244/dygraphs-not-working-with-ng-repeat).

In order to use a legend in an external div and not directly on the graph, the ID of the div that should be used has to be defined in the [options](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#Legend). As it needs to be unique, I use $index in the view:

```
<div id="{{$index}}">
</div>
```

And simply use a loop that counts up and adds the same number to the options in my controller:

```
i = 0
while i < oject.length
    labelsDiv: i
    ++i
```

I get the data for drawing the graph in an array, so I then add the options to the array, store everything in a variable and give that to the directive:

```
drawGraph.directive "graph", ->
    restrict: "E" # Use as element
    scope: # Isolate scope
        data: "=" # Two-way bind data to local scope
        opts: "=?" # '?' means optional

    template: "<div></div>" # We need a div to attach graph to
    link: (scope, elem, attrs) ->
        graph = new Dygraph(elem.children()[0], scope.data, scope.opts)
```

According to the console, that worked (the options have been handled over to the array, id-numbers in the view match ids in the options of the graphs). However, while the very first legend of the very first graph worked perfectly, legends of the other graphs are not shown, the all have an error:

> Object 1 has no method 'appendChild'
>
> Object 2 has no method 'appendChild' and so on.

Unfortunately I don't even have a clue what the problem could be. It appears that ng-repeat just gets the very first number, could it be that the other variables are not loaded yet? Also thought it could be related to scopes that are not isolated, but they actually are.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It could be related to the fact that I'm using a simple ID, maybe I need an equivalent to "ng-class" for an ID?

Comment: Is `Dygraph` looking for a jquery element?  I'm not sure that `elem.children()[0]` returns the correct type of element.  Looks like `Dygraph` wants a native element.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavinTryon, I got that from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468244/dygraphs-not-working-with-ng-repeat?lq=1). And this seem to work, as the graphs are actually drawn. It's just their legends that are missing and throwing errors, except for the very first one.