# show dygraph in list items

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, dygraphs

Can any body tell me how to display dygraph in listview using json response.
Here is my response from which i need to make dygraph..i goggled about it but its did'nt get any clue about it.

http://piratepad.net/ep/pad/view/ro.y8PksMhLIhk/latest

this is how i am doing :-

In My Index.html :-

```html
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/dygraph-combined-dev.js"></script>
<script src="js/dygraph-combined.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

In My Home.html :-

```html
<div ng-repeat="entry in listnew">
    <div class="bar bar-dark bar-head">
        <h2>Basestation {{entry.baseID}} {{entry.nickname}}</h2>
    </div>

    <ion-list>
    <div ng-repeat="scout in entry.scouts">
        <div class="wrap_home">
            <ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-click="toggleGroup(scout)"
                ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(scout)}" ng-init="showGraph(scout.tempHistory)">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-25">
                    <div class="top_spc">
                        <b>{{scout.moduleID}}</b>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-25">
                    <div class="top_spc">{{scout.nickname}}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-20">
                    <div class="top_spc temp_mid">
                        {{scout.temperature}}<sup>o</sup>C
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="batt_icon ">
                        <img src="img/battery.png" alt="battery" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div ng-if="scout.power=='0'">
                        <div class="plug_icon red">
                            <img src="img/plug.png" alt="plug" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="scout.power=='1'">
                        <div class="plug_icon">
                            <img src="img/plug.png" alt="plug" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item class="item-accordion sm-item"
                ng-show="isGroupShown(scout)">
            <div class="sub_detail">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col col-50">
                        <b>{{scout.equipment_type}} </b><span>({{scout.last_report_at}}
                            min ago)</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-50">{{scout.tempLow}}(L),
                        {{scout.tempHigh}}(A), {{scout.tempAvrg}} (Avg)</div>
                </div>
                <div id=graph>
                </div>
                </div>
            </ion-item>
        </div>
    </div>
    </ion-list>
</div>
```

In my controller.js :-

```js
$scope.showGraph = function(data) {                 
            g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
                    // For possible data formats, see http://dygraphs.com/data.html
                    // The x-values could also be dates, e.g. "2012/03/15"
                    data, {
                            // options go here. See http://dygraphs.com/options.html
                        legend : 'always',
                        animatedZooms : true,
                        title : 'dygraphs chart template'
                    });                 
        };
```

Here data is which i displayed in pirate-pad.
The problem is I am getting dygraph only at first item but not on remaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :-

In Your Controller.js Define :-

```html
$scope.graphs = [
       {
        data : data(Place your JavaScript Array here),
       },

     ];

    })

.directive(
    'graph',
    function() {
     return {
      restrict : 'E',
      scope : {
       data : '=',
       opts : '='
      },
      template : '<div class="graph"></div><div class="labels"></div>',
      link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
       var graph = new Dygraph(elem.children()[0],
         scope.data, scope.opts);
      }
     };
    });
```

In your Home.html define :-

```html
<ion-list>
 <div ng-repeat="scout in entry.scouts" >
  <div class="wrap_home">
   <ion-item class="item-accordion" ng-click="toggleGroup(scout,scout.tempHistory)"
    ng-class="{active: isGroupShown(scout)}" >
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-25">
     <div class="top_spc">
      <b>{{scout.moduleID}}</b>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-25">
     <div class="top_spc">{{scout.nickname}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-20">
     <div class="top_spc temp_mid">
      {{scout.temperature}}<sup>o</sup>C
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
     <div class="batt_icon ">
      <img src="img/battery.png" alt="battery" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
     <div ng-if="scout.power=='0'">
      <div class="plug_icon red">
       <img src="img/plug.png" alt="plug" />
      </div>
     </div>
     <div ng-if="scout.power=='1'">
      <div class="plug_icon">
       <img src="img/plug.png" alt="plug" />
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </ion-item>
   <ion-item class="item-accordion sm-item"
    ng-show="isGroupShown(scout)">
   <div class="sub_detail">
   
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col col-50">
      <b>{{scout.equipment_type}} </b><span>({{scout.last_report_at}}
       min ago)</span>
     </div>
     <div class="col col-50">{{scout.tempLow}}(L),
      {{scout.tempHigh}}(A), {{scout.tempAvrg}} (Avg)</div>
    </div>
    <div  >
        <graph ng-repeat="graph in graphs" data="graph.data" opts="graph.opts"></graph>
</div>
    </div>
   </ion-item>
  </div>
 </div>
 </ion-list>
```

Dygraph have some problem with ng-repeat As I read in the link given bellow :-

[Dygraphs not working with ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468244/dygraphs-not-working-with-ng-repeat)