# Chart.js not drawing with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, chart.js

For some reason this chart won't draw when i try to do it with AngularJS. It seems to work fine if i do it without AngularJS so the problem seems to be related to it. I don't get any error in console so i need some help.

http://jsfiddle.net/a3msytdc/

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <graph ng-repeat="graph in graphs" data="graph.data"></graph>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.graphs = [
        {
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8,9],      
        }
    ];
});

myApp.directive('graph', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },

        template: "<canvas></canvas>",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                console.log(scope);
            var ctx = elem.children()[0].getContext("2d");

            var lineChartData = {
              datasets: [{
                data: scope.data,
              }]
            };

            var graph = new Chart(ctx, {
              type: "bubble",
              data: lineChartData,
        });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Chart.js but I'm wondering what you are expecting to show up in your <canvas> tag.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/amsjy4Lb/2/
As you can see it draws fine without AngularJS.

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference between the 2 jsfiddles

Comment: Sorry i had some trouble with jsfiddle, the link shows the correct fiddle now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is your updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fo6f9s7h/5/)

Looks like you made a couple of mistakes describing `data` and `ng-repeat` was redundant.

Comment: Ok thanks for fixing it, here's the final solution since i actually needed that ng-repeat: http://jsfiddle.net/vvx107tt/

I'm still a bit puzzled about what the initial problem was, since i started working with example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468244/dygraphs-not-working-with-ng-repeat
it's of course a different graph library, but it doesn't seem to require those changes you made in my code.

Comment: i just followed the example without angular you provided